# Create a Sass map programmatically

Tags: sass

I want to create a map of sizes using `Sass`:

`$map: (0: 0, 1: 5px, 2: 10px, 3: 15px, 4: 20px, ..., 10: 50px)`

I tried to do it myself, but got the `expected 1 selector or at-rule, was map-merge` error.

```
$map: (0: 0)
@for $i from 1 through 10
  map-merge($map, ($i: 5px * $i))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$map: (0: 0);

@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  $map: map-merge($map , ($i: 5px * $i));
}
```

I create a test for you: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/ad0ece85c3d6e779eef4876cf72f96a4

Comment: Oh, I forgot to assign a new merged map to the `$map` variable. Thank you!